# Android Studio Flutter Linux прописать префикс установки для дебага

Tags: linux, android-studio, flutter

Создал проект через мастер в андроид студии. При попытке запуска или отладки - оно пытается усановить исполнимый файл в /usr/local/, но хочется этого избежать.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
Building Linux application...
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:66 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file
  "/mnt/home/eri/Projects/2024/HELLO/flutterhello/build/linux/x64/debug/intermediates_do_not_run/flutterhello"
  to "/usr/local/flutterhello": Permission denied.


Exception: Build process failed
```

Как настроить проект чтоб собирался без этой ошибки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала очистить сборку через

```
flutter clean
```

потом добавить переменную окружения в настройки сборки

```
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/eri/bin/
```